# How to calculate screen aspect ratio in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've found this code on StackOverflow to calculate the screen aspect ratio:

```js
function gcd (a, b) {
    return (b == 0) ? a : gcd (b, a%b);
}
var w = screen.width;
var h = screen.height;
var r = gcd (w, h);
document.write ("<pre>");
document.write ("Dimensieons = ", w, " x ", h, "<br>");
document.write ("Gcd        = ", r, "<br>");
document.write ("Aspect     = ", w/r, ":", h/r);
document.write ("</pre>");
```

It works fine for my laptop screen with 1920 x 1080 screen resolution and it returns 16:9 aspect ratio.

As we know the 1366 x 768 resolution screen is also 16:9 in case of aspect ratio 
But the above code returns the wired `683:384` aspect ratio?!

How can we detect aspect ratio using javascript?

Comment: `1366 x 768` is not 16:9, `1366x765` is

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1325815/which-aspect-ratio-to-choose-for-1366x768-resolution-to-play-game-at-monitor-phy

Comment: I got it... Thanks..

Comment: Just in case you need ideas on how to proceed: you could have a set of ratios that you're testing for (4:3, 16:10, 16:9, ...) and choose the closest based on your `screen.width / screen.height`.

Comment: I'll do that...